# Unexpected RAM consumption in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I created B1 App Service plan which has 1.75 GB of RAM. I also created one App Service and deployed docker image to it. Right now I stopped the docker image and it has status stopped and it is the only app in that app service plan. The problem is that when I look into Overview of My App Service Plan I see that RAM usage is about 50% - what is using that RAM if my only App Service in that App Service Plan is stopped? How can I check it?

here you can see print screens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kldhe.jpg

Comment: can you still access the URL?

Answer (score 0):

There are a many things that run in the background. If you have diagnostic logging enabled, backups, any webjobs, etc. those things will cause a rise in your CPU usage.